# Can User-Agent affect how CSS is rendered on a page?

Tags: css, selenium, firefox, automation, user-agent

I have a set of automated tests that run daily on a web portal. The tests run with FireFox but recently I was asked to modify the User-Agent to that of Safari to verify some redirection rules for Safari users. After doing that I have noticed that some tests started to fail due to broken CSS selectors in areas where nothing was changed.

One of my colleagues suggested that changing the User-Agent might affect how CSS is being rendered on the page. For example some dialogs that had 2 buttons ("Ok" and "Cancel" for example) had the order of these buttons swapped. Could that really be case?

**P.S.** Just to emphasize, I am still using FireFox and only manually override the User-Agent string.

Comment: It depends on the application. I can say that it may use different style if your application check the user agent and add different styles before render HTML. Some of my applicaions do that beause IE doesn't support many kinds of styles such as scrollbar color, size.

Comment: The elements should have the same attributes and you should try to get selectors for elements based on attributes and not position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just tested this theory on 2 similar FF browsers, one with the default FF User-Agent and the second one with Safari User-Agent and definitely the buttons locations have changed.

With deafault USer-Agent:
[image]

With Safari User-Agent:
[image]